# Expand KDE activities concept to the shell

Tags: bash, kde, kde-activities

Sometimes, I use KDE, and one of the things that I like the most in KDE 4 is the activity concept. At work, it is very useful because I often work on several different projects during one day. Switching to another activity enables me to change the widgets, so that I can have access to folders related to the current project, for instance.

I've decided to use this concept in the shell, so I have coded a small bash function called "switch", which sets aliases useful for the current project, e.g. `alias cdwww=~/public_html/current_project/www` , and so on.

**My question is** : Is there a way I can synchronise KDE activities with shell activities, that is calling 'switch myproj' on every opened terminal when switching to activity 'myproj' through KDE and *vice versa* (bonus question)?

**Another question** : how do I make my newly created aliases work in all consoles? Is there a way I can detect every opened terminal in konsole or in gnome-terminal and execute my function in it?

EDIT: here is the switch function, located at the end of my .bashrc file, feel free to comment:

```
function switch() {

    if [ ! -d ~/.switch ]
    then
        mkdir ~/.switch
    fi

    if [ ! -f ~/.switch/proj.save ]
    then
        touch ~/.switch/proj.save
    fi

    echo "$1" > ~/.switch/proj.save

    case $1 in
    meddispar )
        echo "Switching to meddispar..."

        echo "setting cdproj alias"
        alias cdproj="cd ~/public_html/onp/"

        echo "setting cdwww alias"
        alias cdwww="cd ~/public_html/onp/www/"

        echo "setting cc alias"
        alias cc="cdwww && php bin/php/ezcache.php --clear-all --purge && cd -"
    ;;
    darjeeling )
        echo "Switching to darjeeling..."

        echo "setting cdproj alias"
        alias cdproj="cd ~/public_html/darjeeling/"

        echo "setting cdwww alias"
        alias cdwww="cd ~/public_html/darjeeling/www/"

        echo "setting cc alias"
        alias cc="rm -rf ~/public_html/darjeeling/www/var/cache/*"
    ;;
    * )
        echo "'$1'? WTF?"
        rm ~/.switch/proj.save
    ;;
    esac
}
if [ -f ~/.switch/proj.save ]
then
     switch `cat ~/.switch/proj.save`
fi
```

As per Gilles' answer, here is what I have got:

```
greg@tiny :) ~ > qdbus |ack ctivity
 org.kde.ActivityController-1949
 org.kde.ActivityManager
greg@tiny :) ~ > qdbus org.kde.ActivityManager 
/
/ActivityManager
/MainApplication
/StatusNotifierWatcher
/connections
/kbuildsycoca
/kded
/kxkb
/modules
/modules/StatusNotifierWatcher
/modules/activitymanager
/modules/device_automounter
/modules/dnssdwatcher
/modules/favicons
/modules/freespacenotifier
/modules/keyboard
/modules/khotkeys
/modules/kpackagekitd
/modules/kremotecontroldaemon
/modules/ktimezoned
/modules/kwrited
/modules/nepomuksearchmodule
/modules/networkmanagement
/modules/networkstatus
/modules/powerdevil
/modules/randrmonitor
/modules/remotedirnotify
/modules/solidautoeject
/modules/statusnotifierwatcher
/org
/org/freedesktop
/org/freedesktop/PowerManagement
/org/freedesktop/PowerManagement/Inhibit
/org/kde
/org/kde/networkmanagement
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/10
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/11
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/12
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/13
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/14
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/15
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/16
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/17
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/2
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/3
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/4
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/5
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/6
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/7
/org/kde/networkmanagement/Activatable/8
greg@tiny :) ~ > qdbus org.kde.ActivityManager /ActivityManager
method QStringList org.kde.ActivityManager.ActivitiesForResource(QString uri)
method QString org.kde.ActivityManager.ActivityIcon(QString id)
method QString org.kde.ActivityManager.ActivityName(QString id)
signal void org.kde.ActivityManager.ActivityNameChanged(QString id, QString name)
method QString org.kde.ActivityManager.AddActivity(QString name)
method QStringList org.kde.ActivityManager.AvailableActivities()
method QString org.kde.ActivityManager.CurrentActivity()
signal void org.kde.ActivityManager.CurrentActivityChanged(QString id)
method bool org.kde.ActivityManager.IsBackstoreAvailable()
method void org.kde.ActivityManager.RegisterActivityController(QString service)
method void org.kde.ActivityManager.RegisterResourceWindow(uint wid, QString uri)
method QStringList org.kde.ActivityManager.RegisteredActivityControllers()
method void org.kde.ActivityManager.RemoveActivity(QString id)
method void org.kde.ActivityManager.SetActivityIcon(QString id, QString name)
method void org.kde.ActivityManager.SetActivityName(QString id, QString name)
method bool org.kde.ActivityManager.SetCurrentActivity(QString id)
method void org.kde.ActivityManager.UnregisterResourceWindow(uint wid, QString uri)
method QString org.kde.ActivityManager._allInfo()
method QString org.kde.ActivityManager._serviceIteration()
method QDBusVariant org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get(QString interface_name, QString property_name)
method QVariantMap org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll(QString interface_name)
method void org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set(QString interface_name, QString property_name, QDBusVariant value)
method QString org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect()
greg@tiny :) ~ > qdbus org.kde.ActivityController-1949 /ActivityController 
method void org.kde.ActivityController.ActivityAdded(QString id)
method void org.kde.ActivityController.ActivityRemoved(QString id)
method void org.kde.ActivityController.ResourceWindowRegistered(uint wid, QString uri)
method void org.kde.ActivityController.ResourceWindowUnregistered(uint wid, QString uri)
method QDBusVariant org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get(QString interface_name, QString property_name)
method QVariantMap org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll(QString interface_name)
method void org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set(QString interface_name, QString property_name, QDBusVariant value)
method QString org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect()
```

EDIT : I completely rewrote my script using python, and now the whole project is available here : https://github.com/greg0ire/switch

Comment: in kde 4.6 you could just put a whole new konsole in your other activity with other settings... so your shell reacts to your activity change...

Comment: Do you mean you can initialize your new konsole with something similar to a .bashrc script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Controlling KDE activities via dbus

KDE can be controlled from the command line with `qdbus`. The general syntax is `qdbus COMPONENT PATH METHOD ARGUMENT1...` where `COMPONENT` is typically something like `org.freedesktop.Foo` or `org.kde.Bar`, `PATH` denotes a class exposed by the component, METHOD is the name of a particular action in that class, and there may be further arguments depending on the method.

Here are commands for KDE ≥4.7 to list activities, to get the current activity, and to set the current activity.

```
qdbus org.kde.kactivitymanagerd /ActivityManager org.kde.ActivityManager.ListActivities
qdbus org.kde.kactivitymanagerd /ActivityManager org.kde.ActivityManager.CurrentActivity
qdbus org.kde.kactivitymanagerd /ActivityManager org.kde.ActivityManager.SetCurrentActivity "activity identifier "
```

### Finding out what dbus can do

KDE's dbus documentation is very poor. Each class is minimally documented, e.g. [Activity](http://api.kde.org/4.5-api/kdebase-workspace-apidocs/plasma/html/classActivity.html), [DesktopCorona](http://api.kde.org/4.5-api/kdebase-workspace-apidocs/plasma/html/classDesktopCorona.html)). But you'll probably have to experiment and perhaps read the source (there are links in the API documentation pages) to find out what is available.

If you type `qdbus` with up to two arguments, it will list the possibilities for the next argument. The following shell snippet lists all available Qt-dbus methods:

```
for x in $(qdbus | sed '/^:/d'); do
  for y in $(qdbus $x); do
    qdbus $x $y | sed "s~^~$x $y ~"
  done
done 2>/dev/null >qdbus.list
```

Another way to explore the dbus tree is `qdbusviewer` in the Qt development tools. There is also a Python qt-dbus interface as part of [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/).

### Getting the shell to react

To make a shell react to external events, the best you can reasonably do is make it check something before displaying a prompt. Bash runs `$PROMPT_COMMAND` before displaying a prompt, and zsh executes the `precmd` function. So you can look up the current KDE activity and do something if it's changed from the last time you looked.

Comment: Thank you Gilles, I'll try these tricks and give a feedback later, but it seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Actually, `qdbus|grep Activity` gives nothing back nor does `qdbus|grep Corona` , so I'm a bit lost... `qdbus org.kde.plasma-netbook` gives some output back, but I don't know how to search sub-commands globally...

Comment: This was on my netbook, on my desktop I get a similar result with org.kde.plasma-desktop

Comment: @greg0ire: I may have inferred things erroneously from the documentation (I don't have a recent enough version of KDE to test). See my edit for a script that lists all potential qdbus calls.

Comment: @Gilles: awesome piece of code, but it does only find things that seem unrelevant to me:`org.gnome.ScreenSaver / method void org.gnome.ScreenSaver.SimulateUserActivity()
org.kde.konsole /Sessions/1 method bool org.kde.konsole.Session.isMonitorActivity()
org.kde.konsole /Sessions/1 method void org.kde.konsole.Session.setMonitorActivity(bool)` (nothing found for Corona=

Comment: @greg0ire: Sorry, I have no idea what DesktopCorona is, I stumbled upon it on a search for “activity” in the KDE APIs. What about the activity manager — is there a way to invoke it from the command line? Otherwise you might have to write a short C++ (or whatever other language gives access to the relevant API) program that triggers the activity change.

Comment: Hello Gilles, I upgraded to Fedora 14 recently, and KDE was upgraded to a newer version in the process. It seems there are now a lot of results, but I think I might be very near to the solution to the first question.

Comment: The thing is, it does not seem to work for netbooks, which have a special configuration for activities. More news tomorrow : I have KDE on a desktop at work, and my ISP will open my new line at home tomorrow too, so I'll have an up to date kde for my home desktop. Then `qdbus org.kde.ActivityManager /ActivityManager org.kde.ActivityManager.CurrentActivity` should output something not empty, unlike on my netbook.

Comment: Hello, I'm at works, and here is the solution (I cannot edit your answer but you could update it : list activities : `qdbus org.kde.ActivityManager /ActivityManager org.kde.ActivityManager.AvailableActivities` set current activity : `qdbus org.kde.ActivityManager /ActivityManager org.kde.ActivityManager.SetCurrentActivity <put activity id here>`

Comment: @greg0ire: Go ahead and write an answer with the KDE dbus paths (and accept it, even). I'll keep my answer up for the shell tricks.

Comment: If I had enough rep, I would edit your answer, all I did was searching for the path, the main idea was yours. Really, just adapt your answer and it'll be fine (and less complicated for others to read).

Comment: @greg0ire: Ok, you can edit the answer now. Could you add how to retrieve the current activity?

Comment: @Gilles: great! Done.

Comment: I updated the answer because the API has changed, and I put a link at the bottom of my question if you want to see what this looks like.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I make my newly created aliases work in all consoles

This especially easy when using the [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/) instead of bash. Besides increasing productivity in general (at least for me), it knows the concept of a global (universal) variable, which is defined by

```
set -U VARIABLE_NAME VALUES
```

The variable is immediately available in all consoles and the value is restored after reboot.