# Can libnotify be used to execute a script?

Tags: shell-script, libnotify

Can `libnotify` be used to execute a script?

I want to use a script to play a sound, or even run more complicated programs via the `notify-send` in bash files and other programs.

Is that possible? It seems to use only popups?

Answer (score 2):

You're close, you don't actually want to run a script on `libnotify` but rather create a monitor against the event that is triggering to cause the notification. You may even be able to trigger on the actual message being sent by `notify-send`, but I have not tried that directly, so cannot confirm.

**NOTE:** `libnotify` can only produce the messages via `notify-send` from what I've been able to find in my searches.

To monitor for an event you use `dbus-monitor`. A sample script could be constructed like so:

*excerpt from [How to continuously monitor rhythmbox for track change using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344390/how-to-continuously-monitor-rhythmbox-for-track-change-using-bash/5345462#5345462)*

```
#!/bin/bash

interface=org.gnome.Rhythmbox.Player
member=playingUriChanged

# listen for playingUriChanged DBus events,
# each time we enter the loop, we just got an event
# so handle the event, e.g. by printing the artist and title
# see rhythmbox-client --print-playing-format for more output options

dbus-monitor --profile "interface='$interface',member='$member'" |
while read -r line; do
    printf "Now playing: "
    rhythmbox-client --print-playing
done
```

The above watches the `org.gnome.Rhythmbox.Player` interface watching for the member `playingUriChanged` to be called. When it is the result is read by the `read` command with the contents being stored into the variable `line`.

The contents of `line` are actually not used within, just to collect the results from `dbus-monitor`. The results within the `while` loop would print the output like so:

```
Now playing: Daft Punk - Overture
Now playing: Daft Punk - The Grid
```

The names of the songs are being produced from `rythmbox-client --print-playing`.

#### Determining a DBUS signal/event

You can consult these 2 Q&A's for further details on how to accomplish this:

- [Expand KDE activities concept to the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3543/expand-kde-activities-concept-to-the-shell)
- [A list of available DBus services](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46301/a-list-of-available-dbus-services)